# How to make Rails relations accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been writing Rails for a few years, and the difference between `attr_accessible :person` and `attr_accessible :person_id` has really bugged me.

`attr_accessible :person` makes it irritating to deal form data, particularly with select helpers, which require access to `f.select :person_id...`

`attr_accessible :person_id`: makes it verboser to set AR finder results, like `User.person_id = Person.create!(name: "Hugh").id`

I don't mind either too much, but using both seems like it should be unnecessary. I also haven't ever really seen a preference in other people's code. Is there a convention here I should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know It's best practice to use `attr_accessible :person_id`. The model object will convert to id automatically, so you should be able to write soething like: `User.first.person_id = Person.create!(name: "Hugh")` or even shorter: `User.first.person.create!(name: "Hugh")`

Comment: I'm glad I asked now, I was entirely unaware of how that worked. Thanks!